# javascript regex pattern causes browser to hang

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, performance, backtracking

I have a problem in regex pattern. while the pattern not found in a given input then it end up browser hanging.
According to me this is getting stuck in backtracking.

I use start and end of the string

```
'( )?'
```

I use below regex in place of spaces in string

```
[^>]*( )?(</span>)?(<span[^>]*>)?(</span[^>]*>)?( )?[^>]*
```

For Example, if I want to find the string `"past medical history"`, the regex pattern will be :

```
( )?past[^>]*( )?(</span>)?(<span[^>]*>)?(</span[^>]*>)?( )?[^>]*medical[^>]*( )?(</span>)?(<span[^>]*>)?(</span[^>]*>)?( )?[^>]*[^>]*( )?(</span>)?(<span[^>]*>)?(</span[^>]*>)?( )?[^>]*history( )?
```

The input is:

```
<span style="left: 379.15px; top: 510.55px; font-size: 11.04px; font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(0.918537);">2, woman, with a past medical </span>
```

history notable for infertility and hypothyroidism treated with Levothyroxi

there can be n number of spans but if the pattern not found then it should not hang browser and return from that function.

Comment: Are you able to parse the input as HTML instead? Using RegEx for HTML isn't reliable.

Comment: This is a PDF. so this is why i am thought of using this.(it contains a group of spans)

Comment: You could easily convert your input to HTML, though - `var div = document.createElement("div"); div.innerHTML = input;` - then you can search that without crazy `<span>` RegEx patterns.